# Как в Visual Studio скомпилировать 32 битный dll на 64 битной операционной системе

Tags: c#, visual-studio, компиляция

Как в Visual Studio скомпилировать 32 битный dll на 64 битной операционной системе..

Компилируется 64 битный файл dll а мне нужен 32 битный

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: x86 это и есть 32 битная сборка. А по скриншоту видно что активная платформа - 64. Достаточно просто переключить на х86

Comment: Все виды сборок можно собрать независимо от разрядности операционной системы. А лучше просто поставьте 64-битный Notepad++.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку) я ставил  х86 все равно выдает ошибку) сейчас поставлю 64 битный нотпед++ думаю сразу решиться моя проблема)

Comment: Во-первых собирайте Release сборку, во-вторых у вас окне с вашего же скриншота "Активная сборка приложения" выбрано x64. Будьте внимательны.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/15ims3z